# Blazor error InvalidOperationException: The constraint could not be resolved.... type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Blazor app InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference 'ConstituencyId' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.
Complete app is down ,cant do anything
[image]

Answer (score -2):

It wont give any clue at all finally i resolved by myself by comparing with git changes ,
it was so simple @page root was wrong for one page due to which complete application going down, what nonsense is this  @microosft @blazor team should improve the quality otherwise its difficult to sustain & growup
[image]

Comment: [Polite] Stack Overflow is not a forum for rants.